# Error -3 while decompressing: invalid code lengths set

Tags: python, json, gzip

I have a huge gzipped json file . I am trying to read it using gzip module from python as

```
with gzip.open(filename,'r') as fin:#
        for line in fin:
            blah..blah..
```

But after reading some lines the code gives "Error -3 while decompressing: invalid code lengths set" error .. what is the cause and possible solution ?

Edit: I know that I haven't reached end of file

Comment: Does it work correctly without the explicit open mode `"r"`? See https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html

Comment: No it didn't work

Comment: Then, with the little information you have provided, there is only one conclusion possible: the gzip module issues an error because the zipped document iis damaged. There is really nothing more that we can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the file in binary mode instead; `gzip.open(filename, "rb")`

Comment: Tried that . didn't work .. I am using a redhat linux os